# already defined error & infinite loop

Tags: c++, input, defined

I'm having an infinite loop when I enter any wrong input. I'm wondering how to avoid this, so I can just output `retype your answer` then let it re-enter the input.

Also I am having problems in Visual Studio 2010,

I ran the code fine in Quincy, I then wanted to add sound and i found a tutorial in doing so by using Visual Studio.  I performed a sound test with another code, and the music worked, so I know its not that, or at least think.  The problem that I see now in visual Studio, that I didn't have in Quincy, are these errors:

> 1>stats.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall pokemon::pokemon(int,int)" (??0pokemon@@QAE@HH@Z) already defined in Mainirk.obj
>
> 1>c:\users\taylor\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\irkling\Debug\irkling.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/MHWfQ8WF

Answer (score 0):

The above function is defined at two places one in the main.cpp(or your main file) and other in stats.cpp file.Please check your code or you can post it as well.

Thanks

Comment: my code is pasted on the pastebin link after "Here is my code:"

Comment: i found a solution to one of my problems.  I took out pokemon::pokemon (int hp, int dmg)
{
health = hp;
damage = dmg;
}
health = hp;    from my stats.h and it worked. I wonder why i didnt have to do that in quincy =/ . The input problem is still there though.